# Listen to youtube iframe events using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I have a site with a list of many embedded youtube videos like this

```
 <div class="thumbnail">
          <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2sZAeXBP0NE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> </div>
```

the video list is big and changing daily.

im looking for a way to capture the start video event, so i can force the user to accept the TOS (using popup) before seeing the videos.
I tried to place a div with higher z-index and put an onclick event there ,but its not working/preventing the user to watch the video.

Comment: Why not using YouTubes API for this approach? https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: I checked this option but its seems to be suited for a single video,

Comment: i added an id to the iframe element (video1) and tried the following code player = document.getElementById("video1");
player = addEventListener("onStateChange", function(e){console.log(e.data)}); however the event never fires!!!

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using YouTube API
few things to mention

You must use a div as a placeholder for the video like this

```
<div id="video3" class="video3"></div>
```

and then you may declare callback function that fires once the video is clicked

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    video1 = new YT.Player('video1', {
      height: '315',
      width: '560',
      videoId: 'youtubeId',
      events: {
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
```

note that all videos must be loaded inside the onYouTubeIFrameReady and they all may point to the same callback function or different ones
hope it helps